# Composite key with one component being a foreign key

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, foreign-keys, create-table

I have a financial app where I store ticker data on a daily basis, so i create a primary key from the `Ticker` and `Date`.

I also need to make `Ticker` (which is part of the above composite key) a foreign key of another table called `Tickers`.

However when I go to add the Foreign Key relationship within SQL Server Management Studio, it is asking me to provide link for both columns `Ticker` and `Date`, whereas the Ticker table only contains `Ticker` (which is what I only want to bind on).

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong please or is this not possible?

My tables are as below:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Tickers](
    [Ticker] [nvarchar](8) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Market] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Locale] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Type] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Active] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [PrimaryExch] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Updated] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    [Currency] [int] NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Tickers] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Ticker] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AggregateDay](
    [Ticker] [nchar](8) NOT NULL,
    [Date] [date] NOT NULL,
    [Volume] [decimal](18, 0) NULL,
    [Open] [decimal](18, 0) NULL,
    [Close] [decimal](18, 0) NULL,
    [High] [decimal](18, 0) NULL,
    [Low] [decimal](18, 0) NULL,
    [Samples] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_AggregateDay] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Ticker] ASC,
    [Date] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

[image: studio]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One problem with your set-up is that the parent and child columns do not have the same datatype: `[dbo].[Tickers]([Ticker])` is `[nvarchar](8)`, while `[dbo].[AggregateDay](Ticket)` is `[nchar](8)`.

If you align both datatypes, then you can create the relationship, like so:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AggregateDay](
    [Ticker] [nvarchar](8) NOT NULL 
        REFERENCES [dbo].[Tickers]([Ticker]),  -- foreign key declaration
    [Date] [date] NOT NULL,
    [Volume] [decimal](18, 0) NULL,
    [Open] [decimal](18, 0) NULL,
    [Close] [decimal](18, 0) NULL,
    [High] [decimal](18, 0) NULL,
    [Low] [decimal](18, 0) NULL,
    [Samples] [int] NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_AggregateDay] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    ([Ticker] ASC, [Date] ASC)
    WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) 
    ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=835ae59cf9c162be46ec154347164646)**